# How to use SLF4J to log to two different files based on type of msg..?

Tags: spring, slf4j, logback

i am running a client server program in spring.
i am trying to implement SLF4J + Logback for logging.

Now the thing is my client (which in real life would be a device/sensor) will send me data in string format which contains various fields seperated by comma) exact pattern is like this : deviceID,DeviceName,DeviceLocation,TimeStamp,someValue

now what i want is to filter the message in Logback using deviceID and then write the whole string to file which has name like device.log suppose for example 1,indyaah,Scranton,2011-8-10 12:00:00,34 should be logged in to file device1.log dynamically.
so how can i use evaluateFilter in logback/janino.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logback provides all the features you need out of the box. You need to learn about [`SiftingAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) and probably [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html).

`SiftingAppender` wraps several homogeneous appenders and picks single one per each logging message based on user-defined criteria (called *distriminator*). The documentation is pretty good, and it has some nice examples.

Comment: thanks a lot really helped me to solve the issue and implement it exactly i wanted.!!
thanks a lot again.. :)